# How to write linq query to match SQL like select top 100 * from tab?

Tags: linq

WIth Ria Service, I have a linq query like:

```
EntityQuery<Employee> query = from e in ctx.GetEmployeeQuery()  
                      orderby e.DateCreated descending
                              select e;
```

Then I want to get the top 100 records from this query, like SQL 
select top 100 * from Employee

How to write the linq query?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
EntityQuery<Employee> query = (from e in ctx.GetEmployeeQuery()  
                              orderby e.DateCreated descending
                              select e).Take (100);
```

Comment: Lol. It seemed such a complex question but again, Linq makes it real simple. (I need to make a t-shirt with "I heart Linq"...)

Comment: For the ultimate cred, the shirt would need to have a linq statement that returns "I love LINQ".